# ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (54, 54, 128) (54, 54, 64)

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, resnet

I wrote a ResNet block with three convolutional layers:

```
def res_net_block(input_data, filters, kernel_size):
kernel_middle = kernel_size + 2
filters_last_layer = filters * 2

x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(input_data)   #64, 1x1 
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_middle, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)          #64, 3x3
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Conv2D(filters_last_layer, kernel_size, activation = None, padding = 'same')(x)   #128, 1x1 
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Add()([x, input_data])

x = Activation('relu')(x)
return x
```

When I add it to my model, I receive this error: ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (54, 54, 128) (54, 54, 64)

Here is my model so far:

```
inputs = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3))
model = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 7, strides = 2, activation = 'relu')(inputs)
model = BatchNormalization()(model)
model = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 3, strides = 2)(model)
for i in range(num_res_net_blocks):
    model = res_net_block(model, 64, 1)
```

I believe the problem comes from this line in the ResNet block:

```
x = Add()([x, input_data])
```

The input data is with different dimensions from the x. But I don't know how to fix this issue.
I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to adding two tensors with different dimensions - (54, 54, **128**) & (54, 54, **64**). In order to perform tensor addition, the input dimensions must be the *same along all axes*. Here's the same note from [Keras Add() doc](https://keras.io/layers/merge/):

Quote: "`keras.layers.Add()` ... It takes as input a list of tensors, **all of the same shape**, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape)"

In order to perform residual addition, you need to ensure the two tensors - one along the identity path and one on the residual path, have the same dimensions. As a simple solution to debug the error, in the final `Conv2D` replace `filters_last_layer` with `filters` to get both residual (`x`) and identity tensor (`input_data`) to have the same shape (54, 54, **64**).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now. But another problem occurs to me. I want to add extra zeroes to increase dimensions, so I can perform the Add() function and I am not aware of how this may happen.

Comment: Oh okay, so you need to increase dimensions of a tensor by using a zero tensor. You could use tf.zeros() - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros to get a zero tensor of specified dimensions & tf.concat() - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat to concatenate them to get a new tensor of increased dimensions. Did I understand the requirement correctly?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to equalize the dimensions. But what I did and worked for me was to apply 1x1 convolution on the input_data.
input_data = Conv2D(filters=F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform(seed=0))(input_data)
Thank you for your help.